# Question over regular induction: Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $n$-cent postage can be formed using just 4-cent and 7-cent stamps

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove $P(n)$ is true for $n \geq 18$ using regular induction. I know how to do this problem using strong induction but don't know how to proceed using regular induction. I know the first step is showing $P(18) = 7+7+4$. But then what?

Comment: Prove strong induction using regular induction and then use strong induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you can form $n$-cents with $4$-cents and $7$-cents stamps. If you have used at least one $7$-cent stamp then you can remove that stamp and add $2$ stamps of $4$-cents to get $n+1$ cents.
If you used all stamps of $4$-cents then remove $5$ of them and add $3$ of $7$-cents (here you use $n>18$ and $n$ a multiple of $4$).